# how to link a page url to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress, I just converted my HTML to WP Theme, but now I'm facing a problem, I couldn't get to work the linking of pages.

The structure of my theme:

- index.php
- header.php
- sidebar.php
- footer.php
- services.php <- other page in the site

Here's the sample code from index.php:

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo("template_url")?>/services.php">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo("template_url")?>/services.php#freequote">Free Quote</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo("template_url")?>/customers.php">Customers</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo("template_url")?>/about.php">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo("template_url")?>/contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

But whenever I try to go to services, it's giving internal server error. I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: I am not sure whether you really followed the theme development convention for wordpress or not ..have a look at this- http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: you are not echoing the template url try to echo like this echo bloginfo('template_url')

Comment: I tried echoing it to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways in wordpress for linking `Pages`

For `Content Based` pages only:

You need to create a page from `wp-admin`(Admin panel) and can specify the slug of the page 
E.g:

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo("template_url")?>/services">Services</a></li>
                                              ^This is called Slug
```

This page will always run from `page.php`.

For `HTML Changes` Pages:

You need to create a page from `wp-admin`(Admin panel) and create a file containing
`page-slug.php`, here slug will change according to the name of page.E.g:
`Services` page will become `page-services.php`, in this you can insert your own `html`.

This will run from `page-services` rather than `page.php`

Choose as per your requirement.

Comment: So I will create a services page from wp-admin page?

Comment: yes if you want only content to be shown in services page then create a page name services

Comment: Yes I'm done creatingthe services page. I can't find page-services.php

Comment: re read my question you dont need to create page-services if you are nothing to do with the HTML of the page

Comment: Okay sorry for asking too much, I can't find the page-slug.php so I can just put my html

Comment: let me post an image in my question

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo("template_url")?>/services.php">
```

I think in this case you are just not echoing out the value of that function. Also, however you might want this instead:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/services">
```

The template_url goes to your theme's folder, not to your website's homepage. I assume the latter is what you're really going for.

Answer (score -1):

try `<php echo site_url()."/sevices.php"; ?>`

Comment: Tried this but no page found?

Comment: try site_url() instead of get_site_url()